# How to get matplotlib ax object as output of a function, and use it for plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw several plots in one figure.

To plot one set of data, I defined a function that returns ax:

```
def make_plot(y_true, y_pred, plot_size) :
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(plot_size))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(y_true, y_pred, 'o')
    ax.set_xlabel('Observed', size=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Predicted', size=14)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
    return ax
```

Then, I have a For loop over data to make a plot for every set of data, and combine all plots in one figure. Following is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def make_plot(y_true, y_pred, plot_size) :
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(plot_size))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(y_true, y_pred, 'o')
    ax.set_xlabel('Observed', size=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Predicted', size=14)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
    return ax
    

def plot_all(y_true_all, y_pred_all, fig_save_folder, fig_name, plot_size=(4,4), num_plots_x = 2):

    num_plots_y = math.ceil(len(y_true_all)/num_plots_x)   # No. of plots in y direction
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(plot_size[0]*num_plots_x, plot_size[1]*num_plots_y))
    
    for i in range(len((y_true_all))):
        ax = plt.subplot(num_plots_y, num_plots_x, i+1)   # [row, column]        
        
        y_true = y_true_all[i]
        y_pred = y_pred_all[i]
    
        ax = make_plot(y_true, y_pred, plot_size) 
    
    plt.tight_layout()     
    plt.savefig(f'{fig_save_folder}/{fig_name}.png')
    plt.show()   
    
    
y_true_all = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
y_pred_all = [[1.1, 2, 3.1], [1, 1.9, 3]]

fig_save_folder = './result'
fig_name = 'test'
plot_all(y_true_all, y_pred_all, fig_save_folder, fig_name, plot_size=(4,4), num_plots_x = 2)
```

What I want to get is a figure like below:

[image]

However, I get two empty axes and one plot. If you have any idea to solve this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eaiser and better to just pass your function an `Axes`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def make_plot(y_true, y_pred, ax) :
    ax.plot(y_true, y_pred, 'o')
    ax.set_xlabel('Observed', size=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Predicted', size=14)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
    return ax
    

def plot_all(y_true_all, y_pred_all, fig_save_folder, fig_name, plot_size=(4,4), num_plots_x = 2):

    num_plots_y = math.ceil(len(y_true_all)/num_plots_x)   # No. of plots in y direction
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(plot_size[0]*num_plots_x, plot_size[1]*num_plots_y))
    
    for i in range(len((y_true_all))):
        ax = plt.subplot(num_plots_y, num_plots_x, i+1)   # [row, column]        
        
        y_true = y_true_all[i]
        y_pred = y_pred_all[i]
    
        ax = make_plot(y_true, y_pred, ax) 
    
    plt.tight_layout()     
    plt.savefig(f'{fig_save_folder}/{fig_name}.png')
    plt.show()   
    
    
y_true_all = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
y_pred_all = [[1.1, 2, 3.1], [1, 1.9, 3]]

fig_save_folder = './result'
fig_name = 'test'
plot_all(y_true_all, y_pred_all, fig_save_folder, fig_name, plot_size=(4,4), num_plots_x = 2)
```

Output:

[image]